# Automate desktop application in Robot framework using Selenium2Library

Tags: automation, robotframework, selenium2library

I want to automate desktop application using Selenium2Library in Robot framework. Is it possible to do?.If yes Please provide me the answer.

Any suggestions on this question would be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think using AutoIT you can interact with desktop application using selenium. i have used it successfully when Automating test case for uploading a CV (Located in system)into website. https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: I can use AutoIT to trigger an x.exe file.But not able to automate the the application using Selenium2Library in Robot Framework after that.

Comment: If the desktop application runs in a browser, yes. Selenium2Library is specifically for testing web browsers. There are other libraries for testing desktop apps, but you seem to be specifically asking for how to use Selenium2Library for something it's not designed to do.

Comment: Thank u Very much.Can u suggest other libraries for automation testing in  desktop applications.

Comment: The first step should be for you to go to the robot framework website; it has a list of all of the most popular libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You can automate desktop applications using 'Selenium2Library ' only in case you can open in web browser.
Otherwise you can use sikuli for desktop application automation.